# How to get all permutations of the elements of two lists(A,B) in a specific way (A,B,A,B,...)

Tags: python

I'm confronted by a problem which seems to have an easy solution but I can't find a good way to solve it by myself.
I have a string of max 9 elements in it, and I separated all the elements which are on even positions from the ones of odd positions like this:

```
peg = "0123"
p1 = []
p2 = []
for i in range(0,len(peg),2):
    p1.append(peg[i])
for i in range(1,len(peg), 2):
    p2.append(peg[I])
```

My goal is to get all strings like the starting one. For this example it would be:

```
p1 = 0123
p2 = 0321
p3 = 2103
p4 = 2301
```

As you can see, those are all permutations, where the elements of list1 are still on the odd positions and elements in list 2 all in even positions. I came up with the code below which delivers the desired solution but just for a specific length of the string. I want the code to work with a string from length 1 up to length 9 and I can't figure out how to do this.

Also I'm not sure if this is the most practical way so if you have a more elegant solution for me, please let me know

```
permp1 = list(permutations(p1))
permp2 = list(permutations(p2))

rs = []
for i in permp1:
    for j in permp2:
        r = str(i[0]+j[0]+i[1]+j[1]+i[2]+j[2])
        rs.append(r)
```

Comment: You said permutation, but the example you gave with "0123" shows it's a combination. 

Comment: @Ava How is it a combination?

Comment: @superb rain sorry it's a permutation. But the thing is it's not taking all the possible permutations.

Comment: @Ava Yeah, that's the point of the question. They don't want all permutations, they just want to permute the even-position elements and permute the odd-position elements.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a lot of slicings:

```
from itertools import permutations

peg = '01234'

rs = []
r = list(peg)
for r[::2] in permutations(peg[::2]):
    for r[1::2] in permutations(peg[1::2]):
        rs.append(''.join(r))

for r in rs:
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
01234
03214
01432
03412
21034
23014
21430
23410
41032
43012
41230
43210
```

List comprehension version:

```
r = list(peg)
rs = [''.join(r)
      for r[::2] in permutations(peg[::2])
      for r[1::2] in permutations(peg[1::2])]
```

Or if someone doesn't like the side effect of modifying a variable outside the list comprehension:

```
rs = [''.join(r)
      for r in [list(peg)]
      for r[::2] in permutations(peg[::2])
      for r[1::2] in permutations(peg[1::2])]
```

Comment: I don't understand at all what's going on but this looks like the perfect solution . Thank you my friend!

Comment: Hmmm... Beautiful

Comment: At risk of destroying some of the beauty (and using a little more memory), it might make sense to store `list(permutations(peg[1::2]))` in a variable before the outer loop and iterate over that for the inner loop, rather than compute `permutations(peg[1::2])` on every iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: @alaniwi `permutations(peg[1::2])` should be pretty fast compared to all the work that's then done with it and its elements.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.

Comment: @alaniwi The `permutations` call might even be O(1) :-P

Comment: @Nic0lodeon Do you understand the slicing? `[::2]` means every other item starting at the first one, and `[1::2]` means every other item starting at the second one. You can also  assign to such a slice, which is what is happening when it is used in place of the loop variable. The initial `r=list(peg)` is just to get a list of the correct length - the actual elements are irrelevant at that stage.

Comment: @alaniwi Benchmarked with `peg = '123456789'`, my original takes about 1.6 seconds, with your improvement it takes about 1.4 seconds. Not worth damaging the beauty :-)

Comment: Point taken, and nice to have it quantified, thanks.

Comment: @alaniwi Got it down to about 1.25 seconds with `append(join(r))` (after storing the two methods in those local variables) and to about 1.15 seconds by doing the whole thing as a list comprehension.

Comment: That's the first time I've ever seen something close to a plausible case for using anything but a variable as a `for` loop target. I'd still probably use a variable and split the slice assignment onto its own line, just to make it easier for maintainers to understand the code, though.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Hmm, I'd think that while unusual, it's easy to understand (for anyone understanding slice assignments at all).

Comment: @alaniwi Darn, the construction isn't O(1), it grabs the iterable's elements right away. Otherwise the result here would be empty: https://repl.it/repls/PuzzledFlamboyantBetaversion#main.py

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I actually had a solution which was almost identical to this one apart from exactly the difference you describe (plus the optimisation I described above), and did a bit of a double-take when I saw the use of the slice as the `for` loop target. But it seems that the target can be anything that you can assign to, e.g. also dictionary keys. And of course, using a tuple unpacking assignment in `for` is commonplace.

Comment: @alaniwi The other unusual one that I remember doing is setting a linked list's values with `for node.value in values: node = node.next`.